# Upsampling - The Basics and Guidelines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resolution

Photoshop and other image editing applications possess sophisticated engines and algorithms which allow one to increase the resolution of an image via [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

Are there any hard and fast rules about when you should and shouldn't do this?  Does your ability to upsample sucessfully (as in the image won't look bad) become increasingly more probably after a certain initial pixel threshold is reached?  Is the only way to 'judge' the success or failure of an upsampling attempt by eyesight or are their other metrics one can use to judge the artificially enhanced resolution?  Are TIFF images better suited for upsampling than JPEG? Apologies for the barrage of questions but I am new to graphic design in general and am really curious about this particular feature.

One more question - is there a known application which possesses the strongest algorithm / engine / or whatever when upsampling images?

Comment: Photoshops up sampler inst really sophisticated. Basically whenever you up sample your doing something wrong. Sometimes it makes sense for print purposes combined with a deconvolution kernel but most times not so much.

Comment: _okay_ I _get_ that upsampling is 'wrong' so to speak.  What would you advise in terms of minimal pixel density thresholds and what is your assessment on the commercial elasticity of upsampling so to speak.

Comment: it really depends on why you are upsampling in the first place. Whats the problem your trying to solve by the upsampler.

Comment: I am creating a poster for my room - it's very high res as far as I can tell 100mb in size about 6000px width and 8000px vertically - I want to know how large (in inches) I can get away with printing and it maintaining its aesthetic appeal - it's an infographic so it needs to maintain a lot of detail - I just have no sense of the guidelines or basic rules to follow in this scenario - can you trust your computer monitor, if not, what can you trust?

Comment: In addition, there are images that I would potentially like to create posters out of but do not have access to high resolution copies of them.  What would be the minimum threshold to physical size in these cases?

Comment: you should be fine to 40-50 inches wide 53-66 inches high. Posters rarely need more than 150 dpi even 120 could be enough, depends a bit how close to the poster you want to be. You can certainly gain some benefit by doing interpolation yourself but it may be unnessesery. Better invest your time at color correction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16232/discussion-between-joojaa-and-maxwell).